# SQL Cursor refactored to Python State Machine on Spark Cluster

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark-sql, etl

Right now I maintain a large data warehouse implemented in MS SQL and SSIS that is refreshed nightly via a batch process. Presently there is a nightly ETL process that takes data received within the last 24 hours, processes it via a state machine implement in SQL Server using cursors and t-sql and inserts it into a fact table. This particular process takes about 1 hour. As a learning exercise and POC I would like to dump the data to a file then use Python (State.py library) via a Spark Cluster to process the data then load it back into SQL server. The data can easily be partitioned so it can by broken up into smaller chunks and processed in parallel.
Does this sound like a reasonable strategy? Can anyone offer some advice before setting out on this POC?
Thanks!